# UITableview editing: done button does nothing

Tags: iphone, uitableview, edit

My table is populated with data from a sql DB. When I click on edit I can delete rows and the entry in the DB, but when I click on Done nothing happens.

To implement deleting I use commitEditingStyle:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    //Get the object to delete from the array
    buddies *buddyObj = [appDelegate.buddiesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [appDelegate removeBuddy:buddyObj];

    //Delete the object from the table.
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

}

I have another table in this app and Edit/Done works fine.

The table with editing working is the first table showed when app starts, the non working table is called clicking on second item of a tabbar.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Max

Comment: The code you posted only shows deleting the row. Where is the code that handles the edit/done button touch event?

Comment: I solved. I set a BOOL called isEditing and this was in conflict. Renamed my BOOL and solved.

Answer (score 0):

Check that delegate is set properly.